# "Calculate Code Metrics" Option not available in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am not getting the option Calculate Code Metrics in VS2010 to take the LOC Count. Any Setting need to be enabled for this. Pls help
Abhijit

Answer (score 0):

You have to have at least VS2010 Professional to do Metrics

For reference - http://blog.aquabirdconsulting.com/?p=296